# Scriptlet in JSP - Accessing request objects

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I know its best to use jstl in JSPS but I have been explicitly told to use scriptlets in this project.My question is that my servlet attached an item of Arraylist to the request object and i wanted to loop over that item using scriptlet.

Example : My servlet attaches this and forwards it to a jsp

```
 request.setAttribute("list", Content); where Content is Arraylist<String>
```

The jsp is to retrieve this object and print it on the page which i tried is:

```
  <%    
          ArrayList<String> cont =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("Content");
          for (int i=0;i<cont.size();i++)
          {
              out.println(cont.get(i));

          }
   %>
```

Here is the error that i get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /EnrolledSuccess.jsp at line 35

32:           ArrayList<String> cont =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("cont");
33:           for (int i=0;i<=cont.size();i++)
34:           {
35:               out.println(cont.get(i));
36:               
37:           }
38:    %>
```

Comment: Looked at it .. still getting problems

Comment: I'd also try to not ignore exceptions, but try to read and understand them. If you can't interpret them, then you should include it in your question, not ignore it as if it's decoration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try iterating `Arraylist` elements with `Iterator`.

`out.println` prints to the browser and `System.out.println()` prints to the server console.

```
<%    
          ArrayList<String> cont =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("list");
          Iterator<String> itr = cont.iterator();
          while (itr.hasNext()) {
          String element = itr.next();
          out.println(element);
    }
   %>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried request.getAttribute?

Comment: That works. So to print the strings in the jsp should i just use system.out.println ?

Answer (score 0):

```
first, you must get attribute from request.
<br/>
<%<br/>
  ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("list");<br/>
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){<br/>
        //you can print the value<br/>
        out.printLn(list.get(i));<br/>
    }<br/>
%><br/>
```

Comment: The problem is with out.println

Answer (score 0):

Index for ArrayList starts from "0", so in for loop the condition should be either i